# Папка generatedJava в Android Studio и ошибка манифеста

Tags: android-studio

Я обновил студию до 3.2 версии. Теперь при создании нового проекта автоматически генерируется папка "generatedJava" с пустыми *R.java* классами:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для чего она нужна и как можно использовать вложенные в нее R-классы?

А также в файле манифеста увидел следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чего ему нужно? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Эта папка (generatedJava) уже была в вашем проекте, только теперь она выделена, в режиме просмотра "Android", вашего проекта. Его фактическое расположение `build/generated/source/r/<current flavor>/<current build type>/`.

Классы, которые вы можете найти здесь - это все классы, из которых будет строиться проект, включая библиотеки. Проверка их может быть полезна при возникновении проблем с генерируемым кодом, например, с обработчиками аннотаций. Например, библиотека привязки данных, ButterKnife или Dagger2 генерирует классы Java на основе ваших аннотаций, которые вы можете увидеть в этом каталоге.

Если вы удалите каталог, он будет медленнее выполнять следующую сборку, потому что ему нужно снова восстановить эти файлы, а не повторно использовать их. Это означает, что они появятся в любом случае, поэтому нет смысла делать это.

2.Ворнинг в манифесте рекомендует использовать [дип-линки](http://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html). «Чтобы Google мог сканировать контент вашего приложения и разрешать пользователям выводить ваше приложение в результатах поиска».

Comment: 2. То есть, если я не собираюсь распространять приложение, эту рекомендацию можно проигнорировать? Ее можно отключить для текущего проекта?

Comment: Грубо говоря - да. Если не хотите делать открытие приложения по урлу, допустим, то можно забить на это

Comment: Все, убрал "желтуху" в манифесте в теге 
<application
...
tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
...</application>